# How to schedule the execution of a java program?

Tags: java, mongodb, logstash, schedule, filebeat

I'm using a java program which I'm using to start some tools (logstash, filebeat, mongodb). I need to schedule the tools to make them start one after another using the java program. So how can I do such task? What is the best way to schedule the execution of such java program?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Windows you can use the Windows Task Scheduler.

http://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard?utm_source=7tutorials.com&utm_medium=redirect&utm_campaign=7_Tutorials_Redirect

If you're using a flavor of Linux, then you can use `cron` to do the same thing.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

Just create a batch file that turns around and calls your Java program.  You can pass in command-line paramters based on what else you want to start (logstash, filebeat, mongodb, etc.)

Comment: Is it possible to send a GET request using a cron job on the quartz scheduler? If yes can you give out a sample code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) provided by Java

```
 final Runnable beeper = new Runnable() {
   public void run() { System.out.println("beep"); }
 };
 final ScheduledFuture<?> beeperHandle =
   scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(beeper, 10, 10, SECONDS);
```

---

If you use spring then it is a lot simpler by using [@Scheduled](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/annotation/Scheduled.html)